# try / finally block question

Tags: java, try-catch

Found this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114212/questions-every-good-java-j2ee-developer-should-be-able-to-answer/2663253#2663253)

And I can't understand, why on first case it prints `CoolReturn+1` and on second case `CoolReturn`? How does it work?

Thanks

====================

What will be printed?

```
public void testFinally(){
    System.out.println(setOne().toString());

}

protected StringBuilder setOne(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        builder.append("Cool");
        return builder.append("Return");
    }finally{
        builder.append("+1");
    }
}
```

Answer: CoolReturn+1

A bit more difficult:

```
public void testFinally(){
    System.out.println(setOne().toString());

}

protected StringBuilder setOne(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        builder.append("Cool");
        return builder.append("Return");
    }finally{
        builder=null;  /* ;) */
    }
}
```

Answer: CoolReturn

Comment: Look at the content of each `finally` block.

Comment: @noob I think his objective is to determine why the behavior is what it is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4625650/object-reference-set-to-null-in-finally-block/4625656#4625656

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Consider

```
protected StringBuilder setOne(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        builder.append("Cool");
        return builder.append("Return");
    }finally{
        builder.append("+1");
    }
}
```

as

```
protected StringBuilder setOne(){
    StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
    try{
        builder.append("Cool");
        StringBuilder ret = builder.append("Return"); // 1
        return ret; // 2
    }finally{
        builder.append("+1"); //3
    }
}
```

line 1 is executed, the `builder` is returned as result. Then line 3 is executed, and the `builder` gets appended by `+1`, then the `ret` is returned which is a "reference" to the object referenced by `builder`. The same is for the second case. Hope it is clear.

Comment: It is not a reference to the object reference by builder.  It is a copy of the reference.  If it were a reference then it would also be set to null.

Answer (score 6):

The first one:

The finally will always fire (assuming the machien doesn't crash or anything). So after the return, the finally block fires, and since it has a reference to the object "builder", it appends the extra token to it.

The second one:

The finally block fires just like before, but it sets the reference to builder to be null. The object still exists, because it still has a link to it.

Answer (score 2):

When it does return builder.append("Return") a copy of the reference to the builder variable is pushed onto the stack.  Then builder is set to null.  The caller then pops the copy of the reference off the stack.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, in the finally block, you manipulate the string builder with append.

In the second example, in the finally block, you change your pointer to the string builder to be the null pointer, after you return the result from the append method. This does not modify the string builder that you formerly pointed to in any way.

EDIT: Looks like I got beat to it.

Answer (score 1):

This works because the `return` expression is evaluated before the `finally` block is executed. This is pretty apparent when you invoke a method in the `return` statement of your code and add logging statements to your `try` and `finally` blocks. The relevant explanation can be found in the [JLS 3rd edition, 14.20.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/statements.html). This is one of the reasons why `return` statements in the `finally` block produce a warning in IDE's like Eclipse.

A sample groovy code:

```
def doSomething() {
    def f = "something";
    try {
        return f += doSomethingMore()
    } finally {
        println "before nulling";        
        f = null;
        println "after nulling";
    }
}

def doSomethingMore() {
    println "doSomethingMore called"
    return "-wow";
}

println "output from call ---> " + doSomething()
```

Answer (score 0):

The finally operator always runs so builder gets returned and then the +1 is returned.

On the second one, the builder is set to null, so there is nothing else to add to it.  It could just as easily be builder = "" in the last one.

Answer (score 0):

The finally block will always execute.  http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html Thats why all three statements are appending.